# How to import zipped json into elasticsearch using logstash?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to import the data into elasticsearch using logstash. The data is in zipped format as it is a large data.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/Users/lenovo-pc/Desktop/test.zip"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type=> "mytest"
    codec => "gzip_lines"
  }       
}

filter {
  json { source => "message" }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "testing"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

What I got after running `logstash -f import.conf`, is here:

```
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
13:53:11.640 [main] FATAL logstash.runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<ArgumentError: Could not coerce (9600-9700) into a port range>, :backtrace=>["C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:352:in `coerce'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:237:in `set'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:61:in `set_value'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:80:in `merge'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:80:in `merge'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:115:in `validate_all'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:210:in `execute'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:183:in `run'", "C:/Bitnami/elk-5.2.2-0/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "C:\\Bitnami\\elk-5.2.2-0\\logstash\\lib\\bootstrap\\environment.rb:71:in `(root)'"]}
```

kindly help me resolve this problem.

Sample of my test.zip file: [Check here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95NkREX01uYW8yYjg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you try with a simple stdin input instead? I wonder if it's caused by your setup or by the zip file actually.

Comment: How I can do that? `stdin` do not take file as input I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

`gzip` and `zip` are two different compression methods.  The `gzip` format only supports a single file while `zip` is a container format.  There is no zip codec for logstash.  You'd need another codec to specify the codec of the files inside of the zip file and logstash has no concept for that.  There is a [JIRA](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-s3/issues/38) for supporting it on the S3 input, but it is still open.

To process the files inside of a `.zip` file, you're going to have to rely on something external to logstash to extract the files for you and then use a `file` input to process the extracted files.

Comment: In that case, using `unzip -c archive.zip file1.txt file2.txt` using Logstash's exec plugin should work (albeit on a Linux OS), shouldn't it?

Comment: @asettouf Pardon me!.. I didn't understood. Are you saying that I need to write the `unzip` in my logstash config file and then import it to elasticsearch. Is that your context?

Comment: @JafferWilson You can workaround this limitation with the exec plugin, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

To add a little bit to @Alcanzar's answer, as you can't use directly the gzip plugin, a workaround (only on Linux OS, it might work with command line tools such as Cygwin or Git bash on Windows supporting the unzip command) would be to use the [exec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html#plugins-inputs-exec-interval) to unzip the archive file to stdout, a simple test with the followin conf:

```
input {
  exec  {
    command => "unzip -q -c tt.zip"
    interval => 10
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And a zip file containing 2 text files with one line containing (hello world 1 and hello world 2) gives us the output:

```
{
       "message" => "hello world 1\nhello world 2\n",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2017-04-04T08:04:56.024Z",
          "host" => "de0-vsiaas-1129",
       "command" => "unzip -q -c tt.zip"
}
```

It's definitely feasible, albeit through some workaround.